# matplotlib plot with key handler only updates when mouse moves

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I have an interactive matplotlib window which is driven both by the command line and keyboard input when focus is on the window.

The problem is that the key events while focus is on the window do not get triggered until the mouse is moved anywhere on the screen.

To run the example code below: Run the script, then on the command line that opens, type plot. This plots a window with random coloured dots. Every time you issue plot, it repaints random dots in the next colour. The keyboard event when pressing 'c' while focus is on the matplotlib window does the same, but it doesn't get triggered until you move the mouse.

If this works for you, please report which backend you're using (it plots this on startup).

So here's the minimal working example. Unless you're on a mac using the macports python, you'll need to delete the first line so /usr/bin/python is run:

```
#!/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
#!/usr/bin/python
import time, os, sys
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import random
import cmd

colors = [ 'red', 'green', 'blue' ]
colorindex = 0

def key_handler(event):
  global colors
  global colorindex
  print('Key pressed:', event.key)
  sys.stdout.flush()
  if event.key == 'x':
    print "Exiting..."
    sys.exit(0)
  elif event.key == 'c':
    print "changing color"
    colorindex += 1
    if colorindex >= len(colors):
      colorindex = 0
    plotfig()


def plotfig():
  global fig
  global ax1
  global colors
  global colorindex
  ax1.clear()
  someX = range(1,1000)
  someY = []
  for i in someX:
    someY.append(random.randrange(0, 1000))
  ax1.plot(someX, someY, '.', color=colors[colorindex], markersize=8, label="Some Values")
  plt.show()

class someShell(cmd.Cmd):
  intro = 'some shell.   Type help or ? to list commands.\n'
  prompt = 'ss> '

  def do_plot(self, arg):
    global colorindex
    colorindex += 1
    if colorindex >= len(colors):
      colorindex = 0
    plotfig()

  def do_exit(self, arg):
    'Exits SomeShell'
    return True

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 7))
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', key_handler)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

print "Using plotting backend: %s" % plt.get_backend()
plt.ion()
someShell().cmdloop()
```

Comment: Hint: Create a [mcve] of the issue that allows people to test the case. Otherwise it's all guessing here.

Comment: I've added fully working code.

Comment: I'm running this with windows 8.1, matplotlib 2.2.2, and TkAgg backend. It works as expected, except that it throws and error upon typing `plot` a second time after the window has been closed, saying "TclError: this isn't a Tk application" (which I think is expected and not part of this problem here.).

Comment: It also works with Qt4Agg as backend, where no second window can be opened at all.

Comment: thanks all for your help. Switching to the TkAgg backend seems to solve this. Other backends might do the job as well, haven't tested them all.

Comment: Other backends I've tested now (this on OS X High Sierra): Qt4Agg slows the console down to ~1 character per second input, Qt4Cairo doesn't work at all, TkCairo works as well but slows down the terminal a little. WebAgg works as well.